# Solve "Cron run failed" without Watchdog

Tags: 6, cron, debugging, log-messages

Some years ago i wanted to turn off **watchdog** because it's memory and db consumption, but today i need info about why my **cron** isn't running because need to use *Search* module from now?

Trying to *run cron manually* (*admin/reports/status/run-cron*) return

> *Cron run failed.*

calling */cron.php* and running from server's command line has no return,

**How can i debug this?**

or

**There is any other way to turn on logging?**

> admin/settings/logging/dblog

has no return

```
SELECT * FROM `watchdog`
```

MySQL returned an empty result set

```
function watchdog()
```

still there in *bootstrap.inc*

*settings.php* and *.htaccess* free from any relevant *"error", "watch", "dog", "bdlog", "repor"* keywords (have no *php.ini*)

> /modules/dblog/dblog.module

still untouched. [XML sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) and *Search* is disabled

No *logging*, no *cron*, i am puzzled. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the recording of the `watchdog()` messages, you just need to enable the *Database logging* module (short name: dblog). Once you enable it, on admin/reports/dblog you will start reading the recent log entries.

As for the possible error that could return cron, they are the following ones:

- Cron has been running for more than an hour and is most likely stuck
- Cron is already running and you try to re-run it

This is evident from Drupal code. The function that is executed when you go to admin/reports/status/run-cron is [`system_cron_run()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_run_cron/6), which returns the error you are seeing when [`drupal_cron_run()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/6) doesn't return `TRUE`. This is that function code.

```
  // Try to allocate enough time to run all the hook_cron implementations.
  if (function_exists('set_time_limit')) {
    @set_time_limit(240);
  }

  // Fetch the cron semaphore
  $semaphore = variable_get('cron_semaphore', FALSE);

  if ($semaphore) {
    if (time() - $semaphore > 3600) {
      // Either cron has been running for more than an hour or the semaphore
      // was not reset due to a database error.
      watchdog('cron', 'Cron has been running for more than an hour and is most likely stuck.', array(), WATCHDOG_ERROR);

      // Release cron semaphore
      variable_del('cron_semaphore');
    }
    else {
      // Cron is still running normally.
      watchdog('cron', 'Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running.', array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
    }
  }
  else {
    // Register shutdown callback
    register_shutdown_function('drupal_cron_cleanup');

    // Lock cron semaphore
    variable_set('cron_semaphore', time());

    // Iterate through the modules calling their cron handlers (if any):
    module_invoke_all('cron');

    // Record cron time
    variable_set('cron_last', time());
    watchdog('cron', 'Cron run completed.', array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);

    // Release cron semaphore
    variable_del('cron_semaphore');

    // Return TRUE so other functions can check if it did run successfully
    return TRUE;
  }
```

As for why Drupal thinks cron is still running, that happens when an error in the code (generally one of the `hook_cron()` implementations) doesn't permit `drupal_cron_run()` to execute the following line:

```
    // Release cron semaphore
    variable_del('cron_semaphore');
```

This means that to debug why cron doesn't work properly, you need to check any `hook_cron()` implementation, and see what is wrong with them. The problem could also be an implementation of `hook_node_view()` which is wrongly calling `drupal_goto()`.

Comment: Thank you, enabling the *Database logging* was the first solution. But the dump result of `drupal_goto()` return only the defaults except the `$path`: *"string(20) "admin/reports/status" NULL NULL int(302)"*. And  *PHP filter* is disabled and there is no any hook in *template.php*, and in any other *template file*. And yes, you are right "Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running."

Answer (score 1):

If you have Drush available on the site, you can run this from the document root for that Drupal site:

```
drush cron
```

It should output errors so you can further troubleshoot. Also, if you have drush, you can enable dblog like so:

```
drush en -y dblog
```

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the `Database logging` was the solution to enable **watchdog** (thank you @kiamlaluno), then this is the message after running cron:

> Message Attempting to re-run cron while it is already running.

Manually deleting `cron_semaphore` cause

> Cron ran successfully

but with *Search* module enabled cause

> Internal Server Error - 500

Then just changing this in *search.module* resolved the problem:

```
 function search_cron() {
  // Update word index
--  foreach (module_list() as $module) {
++  foreach (module_list(true, true, false) as $module) {
```